# implementing a javascript CORS example

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cors

I'm trying to do a cross origins ajax request (CORS) and I found [this pretty good example](http://www.mjhall.org/php-cross-origin-resource-sharing/) as a starter code from MJHALL.

When executing the example on our internal networks (2 separate domains), the example works great and returns a result.  However, when I try to expand it to include some of my own code, I get this error

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://my internal URL.67/dirLib/listing2.php. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Here is my code. My problem occurs in "Listing 2". The first code snippet is the "Listing 1" in MJHALL's example, where I simply insert my internal URL.

You can disregard most of the code in listing 2.  The problem surfaces as soon as I try to reference my own code on this line "$rf->p = json_decode($json);" in listing 2.  Here I'm simply trying to store the incoming data in my public "$p" variable in my class $rf.  If I remove this line, I get no cross origin error.  How can I reference my own code?

```
<!doctype html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
   <script type="text/javascript">

     window.onload = doAjax();

     function doAjax() {
        var url         = "http://my internal URL.67/i/listing2.php";
        var request     = JSON.stringify({searchterm:"two"})
        var xmlhttp     = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xmlhttp.open("POST", url);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://my internal calling URL.23");
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Request-Headers", "X-Requested-With, accept, content-type");

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
           var jsondata = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
           document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
           document.getElementById("id02").innerHTML = jsondata.word;
           document.getElementById("id03").innerHTML = jsondata.RF;
       }
     };

     xmlhttp.send(request);
  }

</script>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="id01"></div>
 <div id="id02"></div>
 <div id="id03"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is listing 2

```
<?php

  try
  {
    include("DBCNX.php");

    class reportFunctions
    {
       public   $errors= array(), $res_arrays= array(), $response, $p;

       function getJobInfo ()
       {
           global $dbx;

           if ( $result = $dbx->query('select something from table') )
           {
               if ($result->num_rows > 0)
               {
                   $l = mysqli_fetch_all( $result, $resulttype = MYSQLI_ASSOC );
                   $this->res_array['info'] = $l[0];
               }else{
                   $this->res_array['info']=new StdClass;
               }
           }else{
               $this->errors[] = 'Query failed!';
               $this->res_array['info']=new StdClass;
           }
           $this->res_array['errors'] = $this->errors;
           $this->response = json_encode ($this->res_array);
       }
   } // end reportFunctions Class
   $rf = new reportFunctions();

   $dictionary = array('one' => 'uno', 'two' => 'due', 'three' => 'tre');

   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
       if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
           header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:  http://my internal calling URL.23');
           header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, content-type, access-control-allow-origin, access-control-allow-methods, access-control-allow-headers');
       }
       exit;
   }

   $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
   $obj = json_decode($json);
   $rf->p = json_decode($json);

   if (array_key_exists($obj->searchterm, $dictionary)) {
       $response = json_encode(array('result' => 1, 'word' =>  $dictionary[$obj->searchterm], 'RF' => var_dump($rf->p) ));
   }
   else {
       $response = json_encode(array('result' => 0, 'word' => 'Not Found', 'RF' => var_dump($rf->p));
   }
} // end try
catch (exception $e) 
{
   $rf->res_array['errors'] =['An error occured - '.$e->getMessage()];
   $rf->response = json_encode ($rf->res_array);
}

header('Content-type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://my internal calling URL.23');
echo $response;

?>
```

Here is the code from a revised attempt to move the class code into the main body of the app

```
    $dictionary = array('one' => 'uno', 'two' => 'due', 'three' => 'tre');
    $errors= array(), $res_arrays= array();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:  http://my internal calling URL.23');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, content-type, access-control-allow-origin, access-control-allow-methods, access-control-allow-headers');
    }
    exit;
}

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json);
 // $rf->p = $obj;
if (array_key_exists($obj->searchterm, $dictionary)) {

    $sql = 'select j.jobid as job, c.name as client, j.prjctname as     project from job j left join master c on c.id = j.comid where  j.jobid='.$obj['reckey'];
    if ( $result = $db->query($sql) )
    {
        if ($result->num_rows > 0)
        {
            $l = mysqli_fetch_all( $result, $resulttype = MYSQLI_ASSOC );
            $res_array['info'] = $l[0];
        }else{
            $errors[] = 'No such job # '.$obj['reckey'];
            $res_array['info']=new StdClass;
        }
    }else{
        $errors[] = 'Query failed!';
        $res_array['info']=new StdClass;
    }
    $res_array['errors'] = $this->errors;
    $response = json_encode(array('result' => 1, 'word' =>   $dictionary[$obj->searchterm], 'RF' => var_dump($res_array) ));

}
else {
    $response = json_encode(array('result' => 0, 'word' => 'Not Found', 'RF' => var_dump($rf->p));
}
} // end try
catch (exception $e) 
{
   $res_array['errors'] =['An error occured - '.$e->getMessage()];
   $response = json_encode ($res_array);
}

header('Content-type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://my internal calling URL.23');
echo $response;
```

Here the code is simplified sending code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <script type="text/javascript">

  window.onload = doAjax();

  function doAjax() {
      var url         = "http://receiving URL/listing3.php";
      var request     = JSON.stringify({searchterm:"two"})
      var xmlhttp     = new XMLHttpRequest();

      xmlhttp.open("POST", url);
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://sending URL");
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Request-Headers", "X-Requested-With, accept, content-type");

      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
          var jsondata = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
          document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
          document.getElementById("id02").innerHTML = jsondata.word;
      }
  };

  xmlhttp.send(request);
}

 </script>
 </head>

<body>
<div id="id01"></div>
<div id="id02"></div>
<div id="id03"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

here is the simplified receiving code

```
<?php

$dictionary = array('one' => 'uno', 'two' => 'due', 'three' => 'tre');

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:  http://sending URL');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, content-type, access-control-allow-origin, access-control-allow-methods, access-control-allow-headers');
    }
    exit;
}

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json);
if (array_key_exists($obj->searchterm, $dictionary)) {
    $response = json_encode(array('result' => 1, 'word' => $dictionary[$obj->searchterm], 'RF' => var_dump($_POST)));
}

header('Content-type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://sending URL');
echo $response;

?>
```

This is a revised receiving app looks up a table value and returns it.

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli("my database connection", "my user", "my password", "my database");

$dictionary = array('one' => 'uno', 'two' => 'due', 'three' => 'tre');

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:  http://my calling URL');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, content-type, access-control-allow-origin, access-control-allow-methods, access-control-allow-headers');
    }
    exit;
}

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json);
if (array_key_exists($obj->searchterm, $dictionary)) {

        $sql = 'select myCol from myTable where myCol=myVariable';
        if ( $result = $db->query($sql) )
        {
            if ($result->num_rows > 0)
            {
                $l = mysqli_fetch_all( $result, $resulttype = MYSQLI_ASSOC );
                $RF = $l[0];
            }else{
                $RF=new StdClass;
            }
        }

    $response = json_encode(array('result' => 1, 'word' =>  $dictionary[$obj->searchterm], 'RF' => $RF));
}

header('Content-type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://my calling URL');
echo $response;

?>
```

Comment: First comment.  I've tried it with both * and exact url address, same result

Comment: Second comment.  The first $obj is the example provided. Was just there to test example.  The second $rf->p is the reference to my class as you see in the code.

Comment: I have now tried to move the code out of the class and into the main body and I still get the cross origins error.  Any further suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: yes if I comment out the $rf it runs fine.  I need to run the code in my class

Comment: I'll give that a shot

Comment: After numerous tries, I removed all my code and just left in the var_dump($obj).  It returned null.

Comment: As a side note now running code with the exact URL for both the pre-flight and response for Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://my calling url and that works fine

Comment: that gives null. But I don't think $_POST is used in this convention anyway

Comment: See simplified script above

Comment: I'm beyond that now.  I have been able to return a value from a query on database table.  I think the trouble is you get the cross-origin error even for simple coding errors. So it seems a bit harder to track down.  I will add my current simple code to my example above.

Comment: very frustrating cannot add additional parameter to json request. Can't even use the one parameter to a search on table.  Table search only works with hard coded value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a day of puzzling with this, I finally got something to work.  Here is what I came up with and some observations.  Comments on how it can be improved are welcome.

This is a working example

Domain A = sending CORS ajax request

Domain B = receiving CORS ajax request and response

The sending app  launched from a browser on DOMAIN A

javascript included in header to simplify display of coding.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        String.prototype.trim = function (){
            return this.replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, "");
        }

        var g = {};

        g.formClass = function()
        {
            this.callBack, this.sendObj = {}, this.resultObj = {};

            this.getRequest = function()
            {
                if (document.getElementById("reckey").value.trim() == '')
                {
                    alert('Enter column1');
                }else{
                    this.sendObj['reckey'] = document.getElementById("reckey").value;
                    this.callBack = 'displayResult';
                    this.doAjax();
                }
            };

            this.displayResult = function(response)
            {
             this.resultObj = JSON.parse(response);
              document.getElementById("JSONresposeDisplay").innerHTML ='JSON response: '+response;
              document.getElementById("column1").innerHTML = this.resultObj.column1;
              document.getElementById("column2").innerHTML = this.resultObj.column2;
              document.getElementById("column3").innerHTML = this.resultObj.column3;
            };

            this.doAjax = function() {
                var url     = "http://999.999.99.9/receiveRequest.php";
                var request = JSON.stringify(g.c.sendObj)
                var xhr     = new XMLHttpRequest();

                xhr.open("POST", url);
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://888.888.88.8");
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, OPTIONS");
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Request-Headers", "X-Requested-With, accept, content-type");

                xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
                        g.c[g.c.callBack](xhr.response);            
                };

                xhr.send(request);
            };

            this.onBodyLoader = function(obj)
            {
                this.ajaxRequest = document.getElementById('ajaxRequest');
                this.ajaxRequest.addEventListener("click",function(){g.c.getRequest();}, false);
            };

        }
        g.c = new g.formClass;
    </script>
</head>

<body onLoad="g.c.onBodyLoader(this);">
    <div id="JSONresposeDisplay"></div>
    <div id="" class="">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter Job #</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="reckey">&nbsp;
                    <input type="button" id="ajaxRequest" value="Request Info via ajax/JSON">
                </td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Job</td>
                <td id='column1'></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Client</td>
                <td id='column2'></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Project</td>
                <td id='column3'></td>
            </tr>
        </table>     
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the receiving app on DOMAIN B

```
    <?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:  http://888.888.88.8');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, content-type, access-control-allow-origin, access-control-allow-methods, access-control-allow-headers');
    }
    exit;
}

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json);
    $db = new mysqli("ip address of server", "user login", "password", "dataBase");

    $sql = 'select column1, column2, column3 from table where column1='.$obj->reckey;
    if ( $result = $db->query($sql) )
    {
        if ($result->num_rows > 0)
        {
            $l = mysqli_fetch_all( $result, $resulttype = MYSQLI_ASSOC );
            $resultObject = $l[0];
        }else{
            $resultObject=new StdClass;
        }
    }

    $response = json_encode($resultObject);

header('Content-type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://888.888.88.8');
echo $response;

?>
```

My observations:

1. I used IP addresses because I had no domain names for these two servers. So that is different than what I have been able to find on the net.
2. For some reason which I don't understand, the browser sending the request had to be started from DOMAIN A server.  I could not call it up from a different machine using the URL of DOMAIN A server. That is to say I got a cross-origin error when I called it up from a different machine. **I would like to know why.**
3. The response on DOMAIN B should have some error trapping included to be complete.  Will work on that to see if I can incorporate that.

**Suggestions on improving the code are welcome.**

But at least if someone else is trying to figure out how to do this, these examples may be helpful